# Installling phpmyadmin to Kali Linux

Tags: linux, php, kali-linux, phpmyadmin

I want to add phpmyadmin to Kali Linux. But i am getting the following error. 
First i ran apt-get update which worked successfully than the following.
Here is the output of apt-get update

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit http://http.kali.org kali InRelease                                        
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main Sources                                     
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Sources                                 
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Sources                                  
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main i386 Packages                               
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free i386 Packages                           
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib i386 Packages                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates InRelease                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free i386 Packages
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
root@kali:~#
```

After this i tried the following which is showing error ! !

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
dbconfig-common libapache2-mod-php5 libmcrypt4 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
Suggested packages:
php-pear libmcrypt-dev mcrypt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dbconfig-common libmcrypt4 php5-gd php5-mcrypt phpmyadmin
The following packages will be upgraded:
libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql
4 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 635 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,503 kB/12.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 17.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ kali/updates/main phpmyadmin all 4:3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1
Connection failed
Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/pool/main/p/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Please run and post the output of `apt-get update`

Comment: Better idea: **don't**. Kali Linux is a specialized pentesting distro. It is not meant to be used as a desktop OS, much less a server OS. It tracks the `testing` Debian archive, which is where Debian puts everything that's not production ready yet. Install a *real* distribution to run your server on.

Answer (score 0):

The security.kali.org website may have had a hickup. Try to ping it:

```
[root@fly2 ~]# ping -c 3 security.kali.org
PING security.kali.org (173.246.39.190) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from http.kali.org (173.246.39.190): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=126 ms
64 bytes from http.kali.org (173.246.39.190): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=127 ms
64 bytes from http.kali.org (173.246.39.190): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=126 ms
```

This indicates the website works. You can also try to browse to http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ to see if you get a directory listing. If that works, try again.

Comment: I used the ping command as you mentioned.But i am only seeing the first line. 

   `root@kali:~# ping -c 3 security.kali.org
    PING security.kali.org (173.246.39.190) 56(84) bytes of data.

    --- security.kali.org ping statistics ---
    3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2017ms `

When browsing to the link mentioned i am able to see the directory tree.

Comment: Your DNS works, looking at the "security.kali.org (173.246.39.190)", so I assume there is no general network issue. Perhaps pinging is blocked by a firewall. Try this: 

    telnet security.kali.org 80

Comment: yes it is saying connected to security.kali.org

Comment: That's great! Could you try again to do the `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`?